# How to translate IL Code to AST

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, il

Is it possible to generate an AST from IL code? There are only questions regarding translation of source code (c#/vb) to ASTs ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213427/translate-c-sharp-code-into-ast))

Comment: Sure, you could take the output of a disassembler and parse it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very interesting thing to do. What will you get out having ASTs for IL?  I'd think you'd want something closer to a data flow graph or triples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [CCI project](http://cciast.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

This is the same framework behind [Microsoft Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn).