# Looking for a C# code parser

Tags: c#, dom, parsing, intellisense

I'm looking for a set of classes (preferably in the .net framework) that will parse C# code and return a list of functions with parameters, classes with their methods, properties etc. Ideally it would provide all that's needed to build my own intellisense.

I have a feeling something like this should be in the .net framework, given all the reflection stuff they offer, but if not then an open source alternative is good enough.

What I'm trying to build is basically something like Snippet Compiler, but with a twist. I'm trying to figure out how to get the code dom first.

I tried googling for this but I'm not sure what the correct term for this is so I came up empty.

Edit: Since I'm looking to use this for intellisense-like processing, actually compiling the code won't work since it will most likely be incomplete. Sorry I should have mentioned that first.

Comment: Does it have to work with non-complete code or code with errors (i.e. code that wouldn't compile with the normal compiler?) That's typically a requirement for IntelliSense-style parsers.

Comment: Yea it should work on incomplete code. I'm looking for on-the-fly stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While .NET's CodeDom namespace provides the [basic API for code language parsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.parse.aspx), they are not implemented. Visual Studio does this through its own language services. These are not available in the redistributable framework.

You could either...

1. Compile the code then use reflection on the resulting assembly
2. Look at something like the Mono C# compiler which creates these syntax trees. It won't be a high-level API like CodeDom but maybe you can work with it.

There may be [something on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/csparser) or a similar site.

**UPDATE**
See this related post. [Parser for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c)

Comment: +1 for update too  - it contains workable solutions

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to work on *incomplete* code, or code with errors in it, then I believe you're pretty much on your own (that is, you won't be able to use the `CSharpCodeCompiler` class or anything like that).

There's tools like ReSharper which does its own parsing, but that's prorietary. You might be able to start with the Mono compiler, but in my experience, writing a parser that works on incomplete code is a whole different ballgame to writing one that's just supposed to spit out errors on incomplete code.

If you just need the names of classes and methods (metadata, basically) then you might be able to do the parsing "by hand", but I guess it depends on how accurate you need the results to be.

Comment: Yea I'm beginning to consider parsing it by hand. Not sure how difficult this will be with generics though.

Answer (score 2):

Mono project GMCS compiler contains a pretty reusable parser for C#4.0. And, it is relatively easy to write your own parser which will suite your specific needs. For example, you can reuse this: http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: The problem with these already-made parsers is that they won't work for incomplete (and thus invalid) code. Their purpose is to create a syntax tree detailed enough to generate code, not to provide data for intellisense.

Comment: Yep. But, as they are reusable, one can easily tweak them. ANTLR may be used for a partial parsing. But of course the most generic option is PEG, so if you can get hold on a decent PEG implementation for .NET, and you can port an existing, say, ANTLR parser, you'll get a quick and easy generic solution.

For example, a Packrat parser from http://www.meta-alternative.net/mbase.html is capable of generating syntax highlighting modes for a text editor, out of any generic syntax, and it work well with incomplete or invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`CSharpCodeCompiler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) in `Microsoft.CSharp` namespace. You can compile using `CSharpCodeCompiler` and access the result assembly using [`CompilerResults.CompiledAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults.compiledassembly.aspx). Off that assembly you will be able to get the types and off the type you can get all property and method information using reflection.

The performance will be pretty average as you will need to compile all the source code whenever something changes. I am not aware of any methods that will let you incrementatlly compile snippets of code.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Have you tried using the [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class? This is a full C# code provider that supports CodeDom. You would simply need to call .Parse() on a text stream, and you get a CodeCompileUnit back.</strike>

```
var codeStream = new StringReader(code);
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

var compileUnit = codeProvider.Parse(codeStream);

// compileUnit contains your code dom
```

Well, seeing as the above does not work (I just tested it), the following article might be of interest. I bookmarked it a good long time ago, so I believe it only supports C# 2.0, but it might still be worth it:

[Generate Code-DOMs directly from C# or VB.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214175901/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/willemf/archive/2006/07/24/86075.aspx)

Comment: This is not implemented by any of the code dom providers and throws a NotImplementedException.

Comment: @Josh: Seems you are correct. I just tried, and it does indeed fail. Such a bummer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late for Blindy, but I recently released a C# parser that would be perfect for this sort of thing, as it's designed to handle code fragments and retains comments:
[C# Parser and CodeDOM](http://www.inevitablesoftware.com/Products.aspx)

It handles C# 4.0 and also the new 'async' feature.  It's commercial, but is a small fraction of the cost of other commercial compilers.

I really think few people realize just how difficult parsing C# has become, especially if you need to resolve symbolic references properly (which is usually required, unless maybe you're just doing formatting).  Just *try* to read and fully understand the Type Inference section of the 500+ page language specification.  Then, meditate on the fact that the spec is not actually fully correct (as mentioned by Eric Lippert himself).