# Visual Studio add-in for C#-development

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing, add-in, code-analysis

I want to write my first Visual Studio 2010 add-in. My aim is to create an add-in that helps to automatically generate code for things like:

- implement superclass constructors
- create delegation methods for composed object
- etc.

Of course, in order to know what to generate, my add-in must have a knowledge of the code-file the user is going to insert generated code into. (classes, base-classes ...)

My first thought was to use a [C#-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c). Is this the right way to go? Isn't there any .NET-Framework part, COM-Object or whatever "built-in"?

Thank you in advance.

P.S: Is noticed that `CSharpCodeProvider`'s class `Parse()` method has not been implemented by Microsoft yet. -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by looking at [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xt0ezx9.aspx), which will help you browse through project files and code trees already parsed and analyzed by Visual Studio, as well as modifying them. EnvDTE is pretty basic and error-prone (for the few times I used it). Finding good in-depth tutorials is also difficult.

If you're trying to implement such features yourself, good luck, it's definitely doable but the learning curve might be quite steep. Otherwise, you could have a look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which already implements the features you're trying to code (and much more). Plus it also has a very well designed API compared to EnvDTE (although not very well documented), allowing to use its internal C# parser / analyzer.

Comment: +1 for EnvDTE. I knew that ReSharper implemented this features. I want to implement this only for learning purposes. :)

Comment: Btw, I started to implement a few features today and it seems to be quite straightforward. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get a lot of info from the [MS Visual Studio Extensibility](https://web.archive.org/web/20140812025130/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/vextend.aspx) site. [This post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/walkthrough-extending-vs-2010-to-support-additional-programming-languages/) from the [Visual Studio blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/) may also get you started with dealing with the in memory code file.