# Remove all comment (single-/multi-line) & blank lines from source file

Tags: c#, regex, comments

How can I remove all comments and blank lines from a C# source file. Have in mind that there could be a nested comments. Some examples:

```
string text = @"//not a comment"; // a comment

/* multiline
comment */ string newText = "/*not a comment*/"; // a comment

/* multiline // not a comment 
/* comment */ string anotherText = "/* not a comment */ // some text here\"// not a comment"; // a comment
```

We can have much more complex source than those three examples above.
Can some one suggest a regex pattern or other way to solve this. I've already browsed a lot a stuff over the internet and coudn't find anything that works.

Comment: Why would you delete comments from source code??

Comment: @Roy Dictus: Yes, generally it's bad idea to remove comments! It's a string tricky task from school. :)

Comment: You're right, there is nothing on the internet so you'll have to do your own homework.

Comment: It woulda helped if you could show you tried something, as bad as the idea is.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a completely legitimate question regardless of its uses.

Comment: [here](http://cnbthcommentremover.codeplex.com/) is a project that does exactly what you ask. it's open source, so nothing's stopping you from having a look or a copy/paste for educational purposes...

Comment: I've already seen it. It works for very simple cases only!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp/3524689#3524689

Comment: very valid question. before we deliver our source code to the client, we strip away our comments.

Comment: I could find a few projects where this would be a positive thing to do. Auto-created comments are the stuff that kills baby seals.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9119583/107152):

```
static string StripComments(string code)
{
    var re = @"(@(?:""[^""]*"")+|""(?:[^""\n\\]+|\\.)*""|'(?:[^'\n\\]+|\\.)*')|//.*|/\*(?s:.*?)\*/";
    return Regex.Replace(code, re, "$1");
}
```

And then remove empty lines.

Comment: Not work. // in string also deleted.

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited, not what I can see. Example: http://ideone.com/PVCdm Please demonstrate your claim.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly this is really difficult to do reliably with regex without there being edge cases. I havnt investigated very far but you might be able to use the [Visual Studio Language Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165099%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to parse comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to identify comments with regexes, you really need to use the regex as a tokenizer. I.e., it identifies and extracts the first thing in the string, whether that thing be a string literal, a comment, or a block of stuff that is neither string literal nor comment. Then you grab the remainder of the string and pull the next token off the beginning.

This gets you around the problems with context. If you're just trying to look for things in the middle of the string, there's no good way to identify whether a particular "comment" is inside a string literal or not -- in fact, it's hard to identify where the string literals are in the first place, because of things like `\"`. But if you always take the first thing in the string, it's easy to say "oh, the string starts with `"`, so everything up to the next unescaped `"` is more string." Context takes care of itself.

So you would want three regexes:

- One that identifies a comment starting at the beginning of the string (either a `//` or a `/*` comment).
- One that identifies a string literal starting at the beginning of the string. Remember to check for both `"` and `@"` strings; each has its own edge cases.
- One that identifies something that is neither of the above, and matches up until the first thing that *could* be a comment or a string literal.

Writing the actual regex patterns is left as an exercise for the reader, since it would take hours to write and test it all and I'm not willing to do that for free. (grin) But it's certainly doable, if you have a good understanding of regexes (or have a place like StackOverflow to ask specific questions when you get stuck) and are willing to write a bunch of automated tests for your code. Watch out on that last ("anything else") case, though -- you want to stop just before an `@` if it's followed by a `"`, but not if it's an `@` to escape a keyword to use as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Also see my project for C# code minification: [CSharp-Minifier](https://github.com/KvanTTT/CSharp-Minifier)

Aside of removing of comments, spaces and and line breaks from code, at present time it's able to compress local variable names and do another minifications.

Comment: It is really cool stuff;) But the GUI is not convenient for usage (seems, like it was written just for author's purposes), but it is not hard to create a wrapper:

Comment: I've tested the wrapper on a small real application (two projects, about 40-50 files), and code compiles without modifications

Comment: @maxkoryukov yes, GUI has been developed for private using :) If you want you can create pull request with your modifications. Moreover some issues can be resolved with Roslyn code analyzer.

Comment: I've used your lib in a rush, and currently I have just a well-working gist.

Next time when I will use this app - I will send you a PR with a tiny console app, which utilizes your library;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll definitely want to use the [`RegexOptions.SingleLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) when constructing your [`RegEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) instance.  Right now, you are processing single lines of code.

To compliment the using of the `RegexOptions.SingleLine` option, you'll want to make sure you use the [start and end string anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`^` and `$` respectively), as for the specific cases you have, you want the regular expression to apply to the *entire* string.

I'd also recommend breaking up the conditions and using [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to handle smaller cases, constructing a larger regular expression from the smaller, easier-to-manage expressions.

Finally, I know this is homework, but parsing a software language with regular expressions is an exercise in futility (it's not a practical application).  It's better for more highly structured data.  If you find in the future you want to do things like this, use a parser which is built for the language, (in this case, I'd *highly* recommend [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn)).

Comment: Lost me with the last paragraph... I have not had trouble with implementing my C# lexer using regex, other than in stripping comments. I do feel that comments are a unique part of the process, since they do not contribute to the tokens that must be passed to the syntaxer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

Answer (score 0):

Use my project to remove most comments. https://github.com/SynAppsDevelopment/CommentRemover

It removes all full-line, ending-line, and XML Doc code comments with some limitations for complex comments explained in the readme and source. This is a C# solution with a WinForms interface.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know all the guidelines. Did my edit help?