# Matching a comment (//Comment) in regex outside quotation marks

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to strip line comments from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp)

I'm completely stuck with this, and i'm not good at making regex.

Basicly i want to match comments in pieces of text, for example this one:

> ```
> //Comment outside quotations
> string text = "//Comment inside quotations..";
> //Another comment
> ```

I want only the top and bottom comment to match, but not the middle one inside quotations

What i have now for comments is:

> ```
> //.*$
> ```

To match a comment throughout the end of the line.

What i want this to use for is for syntax highlighting in a textBox.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
"^(?!\".*\")//.*$"
```

This will match

```
//Comment outside quotations
```

and will not match

```
string text = "//Comment inside quotations..";
```

Please make required escaping for c#

Comment: @user1944775 Note one thing. This regex works for newline comments only. //CommentX in `string text = "//Comment inside quotations..";//CommentX` will not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
([^"]|"[^"]*")*(?<COMMENT>//.*)
```

Parse each match for the named [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) "COMMENT" (or whatever you choose to name it).  Quick disclaimer that I didn't test it out in C#, I just threw the regex together using an online [tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).