# delete multi line comments line c# "// or /*...*/"

Tags: c#, regex

can any one please help me , how to remove lines if it has comments like  '//' or single or multi line comments '/*...*/ '

For example:

```
/\*#define                0x00000000*/

//#define                0x00180000

// #define                0x20000000

// abcd

/*#define                0x00080000

   #define               0x40000000*/

   #define               0x00014000 

   #define               0x00000800
/* defg  */

 #define                 0x00080000

 #define                 0x40000000
```

The output should be

```
 #define               0x00014000 

 #define               0x00000800

 #define                 0x00080000

 #define                 0x40000000
```

in C# using Regex or any other method, thanks in advance

Comment: How does your first set of 4 lines get removed? `/\*` doesn't look like the start of a comment to me; looks more like a syntax error.

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com We are volunteers who want to help you with a specific problem. We donate our time; donate some of yours and show that you at least tried **something**

Comment: Can `//` comments be continued using an escaped linebreak (`//comment \ `)?

Comment: -1 for not showing any effort yourself.

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp/3524689#3524689).

Hope this helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp/3524689#3524689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this Regex `(^\/\/.*?$)|(\/\*.*?\*\/)` ([Rubular proof](http://rubular.com/r/BelPTPrHOy)) will match (and potentially remove if you use Visual Studio and replace it with nothing) the following lines out of your example text:

```
//#define                0x00180000

// #define                0x20000000

// abcd

/*#define                0x00080000

   #define               0x40000000*/

/* defg  */
```

and almost gets you what you want. Now, I'm suspect of this line `/\*#define                0x00000000*/`, but if you wanted to capture it as well you could modify the Regex to be `(^\/\/.*?$)|(\/.*?\*.*?\*\/)` ([Rubular proof](http://rubular.com/r/rYdrVLPmb1)).

Comment: @user2156184, you bet, and I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: can you please tell me , for multiline comment(/*.*/), remove string between comment, i tried but its not working,where s i sstring. if (s.IndexOf("/*")!=-1) { s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf("/*"), s.IndexOf("/") - s.IndexOf("/") + 2); }

Comment: @user2156184, you should be working with `Regex`, so you would leverage the `Regex` class and its subsequent `Matches` class that's returned when creating a match. The Regex I provided puts the actual text of the *entire comment* in a group, you could easily modify that to just be the contents minus the comment indicators by moving the parenthesis in a couple characters.

Comment: without using regex, how it is possible please? am not able to delete rows in between comment, thanks

Comment: @user2156184, it's not going to be all that possible with Regex. It's a string matching problem that spans lines.

Comment: what i did is,                                                     static string StripComments(string code)
        {
            var re = @"(^\/\/.*?$)|(\/\*.*?\*\/)";
            return Regex.Replace(code, re, "$1");
        } 
 while (s.Contains("#define"))
                
                {s= StripComments(s);} , is it correct what i did? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your file is formatted like that just do a read line and check with `string.containt(...)` if "`/, *,`" are contains by your string.

If it's the case just remove it.

**TIPS:** Stock the good line in list to display your output.

Hope this could help you.

If not sorry.

Comment: I don't think this will work if he has a multi-line comments, because there is no syntactical obligation to have a `*` on each line.

Comment: I based my self on his example file.

By the way, just check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp/3524689#3524689

You will find an answer there.

Comment: This also will fail if the comment start sequence (i.e. `/*` or `//`) occurs inside a quoted string.

Comment: can you please tell me , for multiline comment(/*.*/), remove string between comment, i tried but its not working if (s.IndexOf("/*")!=-1) {                                            s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf("/*"), s.IndexOf("*/") - s.IndexOf("/*") + 2);

                    }