# Remove all comments from a PHP source file

Tags: regex, vb.net

I would like to remove all comments from a PHP source file from within a VB.NET application. Another stackoverflow question showed how to do this [in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524689/1158522)

I came up with this conversion, but it does not work unfortunately:

```
Dim blockComments As String = "/\*(.*?)\*/"
Dim lineComments As String = "//(.*?)\r?\n"
Dim strings As String = """((\\[^\n]|[^""\n])*)"""
Dim verbatimStrings As String = "@(""[^""]*"")+"
regex = New Regex(blockComments & "|" & lineComments)
srcT = regex.Replace(srcT, "")
```

Comment: Wheres the problem? What did you try to solve it? What other solutions have you looked at?

Comment: It helps to specify the exact problems you are having, saying "it does not work unfortunately" doesn't give us much information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the flag `RegexOptions.Singleline` when constructing the `Regex` object. Otherwise, the block-comments can't span multiple lines.

```
regex = New Regex(blockComments & "|" & lineComments, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

The `.` normally matches any character except newline (`\n`). The `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag makes it match any character, including newline.