# Remove comments from file

Tags: c#, linq

I have a text file like this

```
/* 
This is a comment 
I a looking to delete it
*/
//CALCULATE;     
Language([Dim Currency].[Currency].&[4]) = 2057;     
Language([Dim Currency].[Currency].&[2]) = 2067;
```

I've tried this code

```
var newLines = oldLines.Select(line => new { 
                Line = line, 
                Words = line.Split("/*") 
            })
            .Where(lineInfo => !lineInfo.Words.Contains(wordToDelete))
            .Select(lineInfo => lineInfo.Line);
var newLines1 = oldLines.Select(line => new { 
            Line = line, 
            Words = line.Split("*/") 
        })
        .Where(lineInfo => !lineInfo.Words.Contains(wordToDelete))
        .Select(lineInfo => lineInfo.Line);
```

The codes returns this

```
This is a comment 
I a looking to delete it
//CALCULATE;     
Language([Dim Currency].[Currency].&[4]) = 2057;     
Language([Dim Currency].[Currency].&[2]) = 2067;
```

How can I modify my LINQ to make the result look like this (without block comments):

```
   //CALCULATE;     
    Language([Dim Currency].[Currency].&[4]) = 2057;     
    Language([Dim Currency].[Currency].&[2]) = 2067;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira: Please undelete your answer.  I said that it wouldn't support comments which didn't start at the beginning of the line, but on closer inspection I was reading your code wrong.  It should be ok.

Comment: why don't you just delete characters that are colored gray?

Comment: I think you need to Follow two pass strategy .  First pass for removing all Multi-line Comments ( /* """ */ ) and other pass for removing single line comments ( // "" )

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp/3524689#3524689

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for the `Aggregate` LINQ operator because you're turning a list of strings (the result of splitting your input file into separate lines) into a single string, the input file without comment blocks. In general, reach for `Aggregate` when you want to reduce a list to a single value, or you want to carry state from one element of the sequence to the next (for example, a piece of state that'd be useful to carry with us is "are we in a comment block?" as a boolean).

In the query below, I made the simplifying assumption that begin and end comments will always be on their own line. If that is not the case, then the body of the `Aggregate` becomes more complex, but is essentially the same (you'd need to add code to handle splitting the line on either "/*" or "*/"). Here's a query that does what you need:

```
var inComment = false; // start off assuming we're not in a comment
// assume lines is some IEnumerable<string> representing the lines of your file,
// perhaps from a call to File.ReadAllLines(<file name>)
var result = 
    lines.Aggregate(new System.Text.StringBuilder(),
                    (builder, line) => {
                         if (!inComment)
                             // more code here if "/*" isn't on its own line
                             inComment = line.StartsWith("/*");

                         if (inComment)
                         {
                             // more code here if "*/" isn't on its own line
                             inComment &= !line.StartsWith("*/");
                             return builder;
                         }

                         if (!inComment) builder.AppendLine(line);

                         return builder;
                     }).ToString();
```

To simplify the example, I did not include the "are we in a comment block" state in the `Aggregate` method, and instead closed over the variable `inComment`. Closing over `inComment` could be removed by changing the type of the `Aggregate` to `Tuple<Boolean StringBuilder>` (instead of `StringBuilder`, as it is in the query above) and using `Item1` instead of `inComment` and `Item2` instead of `builder`.

---

Edit: I didn't explain the body of the `Aggregate` method, which might be valuable, especially since other commenters linked to SO questions using regular expressions. First off, you cannot remove all the comment blocks with a single regular expression, you'd have to use a regular expression as well as some additional logic; in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp/3524689#3524689), this additional logic was provided by the `Regex.Replace` method. This is a far more heavy weight solution than is required here. Instead, you want a simple state machine with two states: InComment and NotInComment. When you're in the InComment state, you check to see if the comment you're in is ending on the current line, and if so move to the NotInComment state. When you're in the NotInComment state, you check to see if a comment starts on the current line. If so, then you skip the line and move the InComment state. If not, you add that line to the output. The InComment state is represented by the `if (inComment)` block, the NotInComment state is everything else.