# RegEx for C# comments

Tags: c#, regex

This question in not the same as [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp), becouse those patterns do not suit me and it seems they don't work correctly.

I'm trying to create regular expression that helps me to delite all comments from valid C# code. I've almost created it:

```
(\/\*(.|\n)*?\*\/)|(\/\/\/(.*)|\/\/(.*))
```

but when I meet something like this:

```
      /* " */ string z = /*"hello"*/"test";
      char f2 = '\"'; // symbol " for testing purposes
      Console.WriteLine("/*dfsdf*////****/**//**Hello, world!\\");/**/ //
```

it matches with text in string between quotes. So I need regEx that will match only c# comments but not code(like in string between quotes). I've tried to create it but in vain because my regEx knowledges are too poor.

I would be grateful for any help.

Regards Dmitry

Answer (score -1):

Use roslyn for c# code manipulation and forgot regex. Roslyn have full access to c# code, it is what Visual Studio use behind the scene.

Comment: Sounds like a comment, not like an answer.