# Powershell - Remove C++ comments from file

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, comments

I'm new to powershell and need some help. I want to use the replace function to remove all the comments from C++ source code. That is single and multiline comments:

```
/*
    Comment here.
*/

// Comment here.
```

Can someone help me with the powershell regex for this?

Comment: Powershell regular expressions are not in any way special. Have you tried simply using the regex somebody else has written) (Regexes that match C-style language comments have been written, you will find any number of examples.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[regex]+[javascript]+comments http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[regex]+[java]+comments http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[regex]+[c]+comments take a look at any of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp/3524689#3524689).

In Powershell you can also use `Regex.Replace` but in a slightly different way:

```
[regex]::Replace($input, $pattern, $replacement)
```