# Find all commented line in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012

My project is developed by many people.
Many of the developers have commented few of their codes

I have a lot of codes like

```
        //ServiceResult serviceResult = null;
        //JavaScriptSerializer serializer = null;
        //ErrorContract errorResponse = null;
```

They use // ,they don't  use /**/
How can I find all such commented line in  visual studio 2012 using regular expression

In that find it should not find any xml comments with ///

Comment: Try `(?m)(?<=;\s*|^\s*)(?<!/)//(?!/).*$`, but there might be still issues with the regex. Also, please check the approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524317/regex-to-strip-line-comments-from-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this patten

```
(?<!/)//(?!/)
```

`(?<!/)` means it can not be `/` before `//`

`(?!/)` means it can not be `/` after `//`

Comment: your expression doesn't work, '/' need to be escaped

Comment: @Andrew: it should not be escaped. And as for explanation: the expression matches 2 consecutive `/`s that are not enclosed into `/`s. However, this regex is not the right answer, I am afraid.

Comment: First of all.. yes it does... https://regex101.com/r/mT9tK8/1, second of all **this doesn't even capture the commented text, it only captures the dashes**

Comment: @Andrew: Please check the tags: it is .NET, not PCRE. You cannot test .NET regex at regex101.com. And I do not say it is correct. Same as yours.

Comment: Okay if it is `.NET` then i agree, but are we assuming `.NET` just because of the `c#` tag? And the second comment was @KuttanSujith

Answer (score 3):

Simply try as

```
(?<!/)//.*(?!/)
```

- `(?<!/)` Negative Lookbehind - To check the `//` doesn't contains `/` as a preceding character
- `//.*` Matches any character including `//` except newline
- `(?!/)` Negative Lookahead - To check the `//` doesn't contains `/` as a next character

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression `(?<!\/)\/\/[^\/].*`

and for `.NET` as someone mentioned: `(?<!/)//[^/].*`

Comment: No need escaping forward slashes in .NET regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^\s*(?<!/)(//(?!/).+)$
```

First group should give you the commented line.

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/siACqIy4CJ)

Answer (score 1):

This should cover most spacing cases and work in all VS versions. I believe look-behinds are only supported in VS2013.

```
^(?:\s|\t)*?//(?!/\s*<).+$
```

Answer (score -3):

The expression should be like this:

```
//.*
```

Comment: _"it should not find any xml comments with ///"_