# Parse c# class file to get properties and methods

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parser for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp)

Say if I had a simple class such as inside a textbox control in a winforms application:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething(string x)
    {
        return "Hello " + x;
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way I can parse the following items from it:

- Class Name
- Properties
- Any public methods

Any ideas/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you want to extract such information from a piece of C# code that resides in a string (_"inside a textbox"_), you'll have to parse it. Then see this question: [Parser for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp). It also contains information on reflection, which is used to look at compiled classes to extract such information.

Comment: Use `Reflection` and extract the details.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have winforms application, inside that application you have textbox where you write this class and you want to parse it, right?

Comment: What do you mean by `inside a textbox control`?

Comment: Yeah idea being user A types in the code into a textbox, then clicks "submit" in which my program then gets the items I would like from it. - no existing/compiled code. Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for that:

```
Type type = typeof(Person);
var properties = type.GetProperties(); // public properties
var methods = type.GetMethods(); // public methods
var name = type.Name;
```

**UPDATE** First step for you is compiling your class

```
sring source = textbox.Text;

CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters() {
   GenerateExecutable = false, 
   GenerateInMemory = true 
};

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();       
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
```

Next you should verify if your text is a valid c# code. Actually your code is not valid - method DoSomething marked as void, but it returns a string.

```
if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    foreach(var error in results.Errors)
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
    return;
}
```

So far so good. Now get types from your compiled in-memory assembly:

```
var assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
```

In your case there will be only `Person` type. But anyway - now you can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get properties, methods, etc from these types:

```
foreach(Type type in types)
{
    var name = type.Name;  
    var properties = type.GetProperties();    
}
```

Comment: OP says "inside a textbox" so I assume it's a string he wants to operate on, not a compiled class.

Comment: @CodeCaster actually it's not clear what he have in text box - is it bound to Person object, is it type name, or text above..

Comment: I notice I get this:      `'System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateCompiler()' is obsolete: 'Callers should not use the ICodeCompiler interface and should instead use the methods directly on the CodeDomProvider class. Those inheriting from CodeDomProvider must still implement this interface, and should exclude this warning or also obsolete this method.'`

Comment: @batesy3k hold on, I'll update to more up-to date version

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat, how would I pick out my "public" methods?

Comment: Take a look on `GetMethods()` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx also you can specify binding flags to select private/static/etc methods

Answer (score 4):

If you need to analyse C# code at runtime, take a look at [Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn).

Comment: Specifically,  Roslyn's Syntax Analysis.