# How to read properties of a class that is not included in the current project?

Tags: c#

I have some classes in a folder.Now in another program I want to read their properties.I can read them as a text but I do not know how to treat with them as a class to write `object.GetType().GetProperties()` for them.

How to do this?

How to read the properties of an existing class that is not included in the current project?

Comment: Can you consume the dll and simply instantiate the class?  Are these public properties in a public class?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a folder"? As text files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse c# class file to get properties and methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725267/parse-c-sharp-class-file-to-get-properties-and-methods)

Comment: @DavidL Yes they are in a public class.The program should do this automatically.So I cant add the dlls.Actually its a code generator.It would create the models according to the database tabeles and now I want to read the properties from the created models(and not from the database) to create some CRUD functions for them.

Comment: @nvoigt No they are not as text files but I can read their text by this line:var objectLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\Models\"+file.Directory.Name+@"\"+fileName+".cs").ToList();

Comment: There are tools for this already.  Consider using Entity Framework 5 or 6, or T4 templates.

Comment: @Dan-o But this generator would create repository and application layer too in facade pattern.And even should support code first too.

Answer (score 0):

Given that what you want is a custom code generator, I think it would be a good idea to look over T4 templates and see if you can use them for you purpose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx

Another solution would be to parse those files yourself and generate the code.(Regex or plain text operations)