# C# Read Entities from file in a folder and read its Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parser for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp)

In C# How To Read Entities from file(s) in a folder and read its Attributes. Example In Folder Companies.Entites if there are three entity files say

```
Company.cs
Office.cs
Contacts.cs
```

then how to read each file and process its attributes one by one.

Comment: Did you try to do it? Show us what you tried.

Comment: I Havent tried as I does not know the right way. Only knows that it can be done from reflections. I wanted only simple thing to read a file find the class name and then process each attribute one by one. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by attributes? Class attributes? File attributes?

Comment: Class attributes. Eg. If Company Class contains property like Name, InclYear then i want all these property with there datatype. I want to process each attribute seperately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read you source files:

```
List<string> sources = new List<string>();

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cs"))            
    sources.Add(File.ReadAllText(file));
```

Create compiler parameters:

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
```

Add references to required libraries:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll"); 
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll"); 
// etc
```

Compile your source to in-memory assembly:

```
var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sources.ToArray());
```

Verify compilation successful:

```
if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    // display results.Errors
}
```

And use Reflection to read compiled types info:

```
var assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
var types = assembly.GetTypes();

foreach (Type type in types)
{
    string name = type.Name;
    var properties = type.GetProperties(); // public properties
    // etc
}
```

Comment: The compilation was successfull but was giving exeption on line var types = assembly.GetTypes(); Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'SaiAdinath.Core.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Fusion Log:
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IMANDIASIA\rajesh
LOG: DisplayName = SaiAdinath.Core.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Data/New1/TestProject/ReadClassAndProperty/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is solved as I copied the required dll in bin\debug folder. Once again Thanks @lazyberezovsky

Comment: @RajeshNagda sorry, was afk. Glad that problem was solved

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) @Sergey Berezovskiy