# How to call an action stored in Dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox, action

I am attempting to setup a `dictionary` that will then have its `keys` stored as `items` in a `listbox`.

I have been able to establish a `dictionary` that then has its `keys` entered in the `listbox`, but I'm not sure how to then execute the action associated with the `key`. From the previous thread there was a recommendation, but I've ran into issues with it: [Original Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244455/how-to-store-a-list-of-cases-from-switch-statement#comment19766478_14244455)

```
Dictionary<string, Action> dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
public void SetDictionary()
    {
       //add entries to the dictionary
        dict["cat"] = new Action(Cat);
        dict["dog"] = new Action(Dog);

        //add each dictionary entry to the listbox.
        foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
        {
            listboxTest.Items.Add(key);
        }                            
    }

     //when an item in the listbox is double clicked
     private void listboxTest_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         testrun(listboxCases.SelectedItem.ToString());             
     }

     public void testrun(string n)
     {
         //this is supposed to receive the item that was double clicked in the listbox, and run it's corresponding action as defined in the dictionary.
         var action = dict[n] as Action action();
     }
```

I believe that my code above is mostly correct and that I'm understanding it, however the action line:

```
var action = dict[n] as Action action();
```

Shows an error stating 'action' is expecting a `';'`. Is my logic here accurate? If so, why is the action call incorrect?

Comment: See this answer again http://stackoverflow.com/a/14244589/1906557 and read the first comment.

Comment: Fuzz, you sample code missing the most important part - type of dictionary you use (I suspect non-generic one). Please check exact types suggested in original answers.

Comment: @L4V - I went and reread and don't see anything new that you might be referring to.

Comment: @Alexei - I added the dictionary type. I apologize for the omission.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a `;`:

```
var action = dict[n] as Action; action();
                              ↑
```

Answer (score 7):

First off, I'm assuming the definition of the dictionary, since it wasn't listed is the following:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> dict;
```

Please indicate what the definition is if that doesn't match.

To execute the action for a given key all you need is:

```
dict[key]();
```

or

```
dict[key].Invoke();
```

To store it as a variable you (shouldn't) need a cast at all:

```
Action action = dict[key];
```

If you do need to cast it (meaning your dictionary definition differs from what I listed), you can do so like this:

```
Action action = dict[key] as Action;
```

You can then invoke it as shown above:

```
action();
```

or

```
action.Invoke();
```

Comment: No need to use as operator, can straight away invoke the Action dict[key]();

Comment: @NasmiSabeer Did you read my answer?  I started off saying that right off of the bat.  When I got to the `as` operator I specifically stated it would only be appropriate if the signature of the `Dictionary` didn't match, i.e. if it was a `Dictionary<string, object>` that happened to contain `Action` objects as the value.

Comment: sorry, my bad didn't read the answer in full

Answer (score 1):

Your testrun should be

```
public void testrun(string n)
{
     //this is supposed to receive the item that was double clicked in the listbox, and run it's corresponding action as defined in the dictionary.
     dict[n]();
}
```

Based on the assumption your dictionary is `Dictionary<string, Action>` as @Servy suggested