# Create and run dictionary of actions

Tags: c#, dictionary, action

I'm trying to create a dictionary of actions and then run them in a loop. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264317/how-to-call-an-action-stored-in-dictionary) question helped, but I still get a compile error when adding the action to the dictionary:- `No overload for 'Action' matches delegate 'Action'.`

Thanks for any help.

```
Dictionary<string, Action> dActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
            // do the actions need to be created?
            Action<string, int> actSpot = new Action<string, int>(oBSM.Spot);
            Action<string, int> actDelta = new Action<string, int>(oBSM.Delta);
            dActions["Spot"] = new Action(actSpot);
            dActions["Delta"] = new Action(actDelta);

            // or add action to dictionary?
            dActions.Add("Spot", oBSM.Spot(string BookOrComp, int DP);
            dActions.Add("Delta", oBSM.Delta(string BookOrComp, int DP);

            foreach (var BookOrComp in ListBookOrComp)
            {
                foreach (string Key in dActions.Keys)
                {
                    for (int DP = 1; DP <= 21; DP++)
                    {
                        dActions[Key]();
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Update**:
I still get a couple of compile errors as show in the code

```
Dictionary<string, Action> dActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
            // create actions
            Action<string, int> actSpot = new Action<string, int>(oBSM.Spot);  
            Action<string, int> actDelta = new Action<string, int>(oBSM.Delta);  
            dActions["Spot"] = new Action(actSpot); // no overload for Action matches delegate Action
            dActions["Delta"] = new Action(actDelta); // ditto


            foreach (var BookOrComp in ListBookOrComp)
            {
                foreach (string Key in dActions.Keys)
                {
                    for (int DP = 1; DP <= 21; DP++)
                    {
                        dActions[Key](BookOrComp,DP);  // delegate Action  does not take 2 arguments
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of erros in your program:

1- Parenthesis are not balanced in:

```
        // or add action to dictionary?
        dActions.Add("Spot", oBSM.Spot(string BookOrComp, int DP);
        dActions.Add("Delta", oBSM.Delta(string BookOrComp, int DP);
```

You need to add a closing parenthesis there. Besides, I am not sure if that syntax is correct, I'd create an object and then add it to the dictionary.

2- The action takes two parameters one string and one int:

```
        Action<string, int> actSpot = new Action<string, int>(oBSM.Spot);
        Action<string, int> actDelta = new Action<string, int>(oBSM.Delta);
```

But you are calling it using now parameters at all:

```
         foreach (var BookOrComp in ListBookOrComp)
        {
            foreach (string Key in dActions.Keys)
            {
                for (int DP = 1; DP <= 21; DP++)
                {
                    dActions[Key](); // <<<-- where are the parameters?
                }
            }
        }
```

I think this is the error the compiler is complaining about.

**Update 2:**

```
Dictionary<string, Action> dActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
```

Should be defined as:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<string, int>> dActions
```

= new Dictionary>();

And

```
        dActions["Spot"] = new Action(actSpot); // no overload for Action matches delegate Action
```

Should be

```
        dActions["Spot"] = actSpot; // actSpot already created with new Action...
```

or:

```
        dActions["Spot"] = new Action<string, int>(oBSM.Spot);
```

PS:

You must understand that when you do this:

```
        dActions["Delta"] = new Action(actDelta); // ditto
```

You are  calling the constructor of `Action` with a parameter of type `Action<string. int>`, and `Action` does not have that constructor.

Comment: Thanks - stupid of me to miss the parenthesis. I agree to create the object and then add it to the dictionary. I tried this in the line ``dActions["Spot"] = new Action(actSpot);`` but got a compile error. Adding the parameters to the calling line also gave a compile error: ``dActions[Key](BookOrComp,DP);``

Comment: Juan, I followed your answer but still get compile errors - see my update. Can you take another look?

Comment: The simple method of ``dActions.Add("Spot", actSpot);         dActions.Add("Delta", actDelta);`` seems to be working. Is this the correct way of adding actions to a dictionary?

Comment: yes, that works (it fails only if the key is already in the dictionary)