# RegEx pattern or algorithm to get part of string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want a easy solution to get part of string in C#.
The string structure is like C++ blocks.

`class aaa{ void bbb(){   ccc {...} text1 } text2}`

The string I want is to get a specified block of code like following.

`string.blocks.second() :`  which should return :
`{   ccc {...} text1 }`

Comment: Don't parse source code using regular expressions. That's just as bad as parsing HTML with regexes.

Comment: @ThiefMaster is right - any grammar that includes nested structures, like the {} in C-like languages, is ill-suited to parsing by regular expressions. In many regex dialects, it's impossible; in the .NET dialect it's possible but difficult to do, difficult to read, difficult to debug, and really slow. A classic example of "[now you have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are talking about source code, you should look at C-like language parsers. They are discussed here: [Parser for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp)