# Regex to parse C# source code

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

i am in the process of creation of simple Document Map for the following C# source.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string DoSomething(string x)
    {
        return "Hello " + x;
    }
}
```

The results should be presented in treeview or listview, in following manner:

```
Person
-- Name
-- Age
-- DoSomething()
```

So, question is, is there a regex or library which handles C# source code?

Comment: any reason for not reflecting on it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp

Comment: Use Roslyn.  Under no circumstance is it remotely possible to parse something as complex as the C# language using regex.  (regex can't even parse html)

Answer (score 7):

You absolutely cannot use a regex to parse C# source as C# does not have a regular grammar.

You could use Roslyn though: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx

Alternatively, use the current C# compiler (or the `System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp").CompileAssemblyFromSource()` method) to compile the code to a new assembly, load that assembly and use reflection to analyse it.

Comment: So, even for this simple situation i need to use another library? I will check on Roslyn.

Comment: @Jim, parsing the C# language is one of the more complicated tasks you could ask a computer to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio already has something of the sort. you can use the arrow next to a CS file to click through and get a list of all methods and variables in that file. it even shows a padlock if they're private.

Comment: Thank you ... but I need to implement it in my application and not VS.

Comment: Why does your app need such an insight into its own code?

Comment: As per my description I need a document map of a c# code...

Comment: @nzall, unless the OP is asking how to perform a felony, it is thoroughly beside the point to inquire his rationale on why he wants to programmatically perform whatever task he wants to perform.