# How to find function inside struct

Tags: regex

```
struct mbuh
(

lineshg = 0,
tres = "text",

    fn track all:#() = 
        (
        local c -- clone
            local lpoint = [0,0,0] -- previous point created
            local ccoll = #() -- array for created objects
            local prev = [0,0] -- var for alt distance changing
        ),

    fn listzfun trs:123 x:#() = 
        (
        obj = snapshotasmesh a
            min_vz = max_vz = in coordsys world (getvert obj 1).z
            min_vx = max_vx = in coordsys world (getvert obj 1).x
            min_vy = max_vy = in coordsys world (getvert obj 1).y
        )
)

fn brung man: =
(

)
```

as the example above , I want to find word "**struct xx**" & "**fn xxx**" but only "**fn xxx**" that  inside struct scope not outside it ["**fn brung xxx**"], I use this regex to find it

```
^.*?(\bstruct\s*\w+\b)|^.?(\bfn\b+[\w\s:#()""]*)
```

but its search all **fn** word inside and outside struct scope, so the question is how can I find word **fn xxx** that only inside struct scope which is in example above [**fn track xxx and fn listzfun xxx**] ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I do think that [regex is _not_ suitable for parsing source code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19639012/107625). You should [use a lexer](http://parsingintro.sourceforge.net/#contents_item_5) instead.

Comment: While it's possible to do this with Regex, stuff like parenthesis/brackets balancing is very tricky to do with just Regex alone. I'd recommend doing another form of parsing on this first if nothing else.

Comment: But is it hard to do that? as additional info ,each  "fn" inside struct separated by coma, while "fn" outside it does not separated by coma.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like so with this regex:

```
(struct\s*\w+.*?(?=fn))(fn.*?(?=\),)\)).*?(?=fn)(fn.*?\))(?=\R\))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zGAt4D/9

Comment: Thanks man , I'' try to develop it. But /R give me an error in c# 4 tho. it said "does not support \R to match a Unicode line break" . Thanks

Comment: @fajarvashra I have no idea about `c#`. Remember to switch on the Single line flag. i.e `.` should match everything including newline.

Comment: I use regex conversion to c# regex but it doesn't show any result
[code]
@"struct\s*\w+.*?(?=fn)(fn.*?(?=\),)\)).*?(?=fn)(fn.*?\))(?=(?>\r\n|[\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029])\))"[/code]

Comment: @fajarvashra Also use a Raw string.

Comment: can you explain  by use raw string ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same equation as the same as MYGz does but its in c#

```
@"\bstruct\s*\w+\s
\(
(?>
[^()]+
|
\((?<Depth>)
|
\)(?<-Depth>)
)*
(?(Depth)(?!))
\)
"
```

Hope this help someone else in the future.