# Check via reflection if specific extension method is used inside the method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was wandering, if I have code like this in some DLL:

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public void TestAction(XMParams command)
    {
        var firstName = command.Parse<string>(Params.First, "First Name");
        var lastName = command.Parse<string>(Params.Second, "Last Name");

        var userData = new UserDataDto{
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName
        }

        command.StoreValue(userData, "User Data");
    }
}
```

Is it posible to detect these lines where **command.Parse** is used, and to extract these data:
command.Parse<**Type**>(**Index**, **Description**)

and

command.StoreValue(**Type**, **DescriptiveName**);

Into this the list of objects which looks like this one:

```
public class InputParamObj
{
    public int Index {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
public class OutputObj
{
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
public class CommandData
{
    public List<InputParamObj> InputParams {get;set;}
    public OutputObj Output {get;set;}
}
```

Note, this piece of code will always be in known method for example inside the "TestAction" method.

Comment: Sounds like not a reflection task at all. Reflection is a metadata API, allowing to get info about types, methods etc, not about how and from where they are called. I think what you want is called interception and is another world. Please look here for one example of these technique (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do that kind of stuff via reflection. With `MethodInfo.GetMethodBody()` you could get the binary IL Stream for the method implementation, but good luck working with that.

You need to parse your code. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp) to see a nice list of solutions. Most of them are good, depending on your real needs. I would personally go with [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/), the new 'compiler as a service' from Microsoft, because from what I saw, it is really a great api: lots of power and pretty well written. But it may not suit your needs right now.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at Mono.Cecil, it's really awesome!
I will have to do some manual and dirty job to get what I want but it can be done. I will let you know if I found some better way.