# Get enums along with their documentation in C#

Tags: c#

I want to convert all C# enums to markdown documentation. I am still considering two options: C# native way and custom grammar implementation. The second may lead to perfect implementation but I have not touched the bison for tens of years.

One C# way is described here: https://dzone.com/articles/converting-c-enums-to-javascript

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumToString<T>(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>();
    var enumDictionary = values.ToDictionary(value => Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value));           return new MvcHtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(enumDictionary));
}
```

Good point is that I can use this method to generate a MD file. Unfortunatelly [C# API](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=net-5.0) does not provide a method to get the enum documentation:

```
/// <summary>pecial forces cars</summary>
C = 1,
```

Is there a way to overcome this limimation? Can [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=net-5.0) provide the field documentation? I cannot find such method.

I have read [Parser for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp) and it seems that Roslyn may be helpful too. Would it be a good approach? It is a C# compiler so I worry it is too heavy weight for my use case.

Comment: You won't get XML docs using reflection -- you'll have to load up the xml docs file yourself. It would be a lot easier to use Roslyn to analyse the C# file

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to have *meta* information attached to enum. This is achieved by utilizing *attributes*. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1799370/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr: yes, parsing output XML seems legit and much easier than learning Roslyn

Comment: @canton7 thanks, so my search was correct